# DataGridView CellMouseMove Row backcolor change

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

It works for only a specific cell. What if I want to change the color of the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the rows and the cells and set the BackColor for them to a color

```
//Loop through all of the rows
for( int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++ ) {

    //Set a variable called row for quick access to the current row
    var row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];

    //Loop through all the cells in row
    for( int x = 0; x < row.Cells.Count; x++ ) {

        //Set the cell to a variable for quick access
        var cell = row.Cells[x];

        //Set the back color of the cell to your desired color
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

This'll determine the amount of rows, then loop through them, and in each row, determine the amount of cells and loop through them, then set the back color of that specific cell to your desired color.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the whole row with:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

This will change each rows back color when the mouse moves over it, however this will not change it back... so as your mouse rolls over each cell, each row will change color and NOT change back to default white when the mouse leaves the cell. Below is some code to change the color back to white when the mouse leaves the cell. You will have to check for other events such as when the user enters text in a cell, as the cell will remain the changed color when you move the mouse away.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```